# WPF DataGrid Color of several Columns based on rules

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I started to develop an WPF App and now I have integrated a DataGrid with some decimal values. Those values are like EBIT-Marge, RoE and so on.

Now I would like to know how to color the cell in case the EBIT-Marge is over 12 and how to color the cell if the RoE is under 20.

When I developed ASP.NET with a Grid I had the OnRowDataBound-Event to do the stuff.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Rayk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use converter to do this ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)).

Example:

`ColorConverter` converter:

```
class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && parameter != null)
        {
            double? dValue = value as double?;
            if (!dValue.HasValue) return Binding.DoNothing;

            var items = parameter.ToString().Split(' ');
            if(items.Length == 2)
            {
                double cValue;
                if(!double.TryParse(items[1], out cValue))
                    return Binding.DoNothing;

                switch (items[0])
                {
                    case "<":
                        if (dValue.Value < cValue)
                            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        break;
                    case ">":
                        if (dValue.Value > cValue)
                            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Convrter `ColorConveter` takes as parameter string with your expression e.g. '> 12' or '< 20'.

XAML code:

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EBIT}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding EBIT, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter='&gt; 12'}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RoE}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RoE, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter='&lt; 20'}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
...
```

**Solution 2:**

Data class:

```
class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _RoE;
    public double RoE
    {
        get { return _RoE; }
        set 
        { 
            _RoE = value;
            if (value < 10)
                RoEColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            else if (value > 20)
                RoEColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            else
                RoEColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            OnPropertyChanged("RoE");
        }
    }

    private SolidColorBrush _RoEColor;
    public SolidColorBrush RoEColor
    {
        get { return _RoEColor; }
        set { _RoEColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("RoEColor"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Now you should binding `RoEColor` to `TextBlock` background property.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>               
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RoE}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RoEColor}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Very nice! The ConvertParameter is the key. But what if I have three ranges smaller than 2 is red bigger than 12 is green. and between white. Should I just extend the ConverterParamenter?

Comment: Yes, you should extend `ConverterParameter` :)

Comment: hmm is it possible to pass another property value from the binding object. e.g. RoEColor... My concern here is that I don't want to keep the validation logic within the converter class. maybe I can pass the result over the parameter?

Comment: @Rayk check my answer again (solution 2) :)

Comment: Yes thats what I am searching for. Thanks!